# Autowired service in conjunction with valueChangeListener

Tags: spring, jsf, autowired, valuechangelistener

I have a valuechangelistener from the JSF core library like this

```
           <h:column>
                <h:form>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox onchange="submit()">
                        <f:valueChangeListener type="be.kdg.repaircafe.listeners.AssignBid"/>
                        <f:attribute name="bid" value="#{b}"/>
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </h:form>
            </h:column>
```

The attribute bid is being passed correctly.

The code for the listener:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class AssignBid implements ValueChangeListener{

    @Autowired
    private RepairService repairService;

    //TODO: repairService null for some reason
    @Override
    public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        Boolean assigned = (Boolean) event.getNewValue();
        Bid b = (Bid) ((UIInput) event.getSource()).getAttributes().get("bid");
        if(assigned){
            repairService.acceptBid(b);
        } else {
            repairService.clearBid(b);
        }
    }
```

}

The problem is repairService always throws a NullPointerException, for some reason it always resolves to null. Everywhere else in my project where I make use of this service I have absolutely no problems with it.

I'm sure it's possible because it did work yesterday, today I changed some code, forgot what I changed exactly and suddenly it broke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change valuechangelistener type to binding

```
<f:valueChangeListener binding="#{assignBid}" />
```